# How can i do it with list comprehension?

Tags: python

I want to make a list comprehension with duplicated values at one loop cycle like this:

```
s=[]
for i in range(5): 
    s+=[i,i]
```

But this doesnt work.

```
[i, i for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: Can you explain better , like what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: `[[i, i] for i in range(5)]`. But you could do `list(map(lambda i: [i, i], range(5)))` as well.

Comment: *But i have no idea how to do it.*, do what?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
[i for i in range(5) for j in range(2)]
```

The output is:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

The `i` loop provides the values, and the `j` loop serves to repeat those values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with `zip`:

```
[i for p in zip(range(5), range(5)) for i in p]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to use a single level list comprehension to do exactly the same thing you're doing with your explicit loop. That's because each iteration of the loop in a comprehension must produce at most one value (it can produce zero if you have an `if` clause).

However, for this specific case, you can use division to produce the sequence of repeated values you want while iterating on a larger `range`:

```
s = [i//2 for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Why it produces two values at one division operation?

Comment: It doesn't make two values at once, just one. But the floor division means we get the same value twice in a row. For instance, `0 // 2` and `1 // 2` are both `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.
`[ i/2 for i in range(10)]`

List comprehension will have as many elements as the iterator within the comprehension. In this case, the iterator is `range(10)`

Since, you need 10 elements. You will need to range over 10 and apply some computation( in this case `i/2`) to get the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

`s = [[i, i] for i in range(5)]`.

And if you want it to be flattened you can try this nested list comprehension.

```
s = [x for y in [[i, i] for i in range(5)] for x in y]
```

Comment: This is a good way too. But simple is better than complex ?